# Nginx RTMP web server

Tags: nginx, openssl, webserver, rtmp

I want to build a Nginx RTMP server.
I am using https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module to build it.
I am working on MacOS.

Following are my build steps:

1. wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.12.1.tar.gz
2. tar -zxvf nginx-1.12.1.tar.gz
3. wget https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/archive/master.zip
4. unzip master.zip
5. cd nginx-1.12.1
6. ./configure --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module-master

Till here everything is working smooth

Now when I run 'make' command, it raises following errors:

> **Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:**
>
> **"_SSL_CIPHER_find", referenced from:**
>
> ```
> _ngx_ssl_get_ciphers in ngx_event_openssl.o
> ```
>
> **"_X509_check_host", referenced from:**
>
> ```
> _ngx_ssl_check_host in ngx_event_openssl.o
> ```
>
> **ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64**
>
> **clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
>
> make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
>
> make: *** [build] Error 2

I have gone through many posts regarding this behaviour and all I found was that this issue may be related to openssl path

If I try to print the openssl path

> $ *which openssl*
>
> **/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl**

I have used homebrew to install openssl.

Can anyone give me right direction to proceed further ?

Comment: [nginx ./configure can't find openssl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23799/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: try `./configure --with-cc-opt='-I/usr/local/opt/pcre/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include' --with-ld-opt='-L/usr/local/opt/pcre/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib' --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module-master`